# Stuck with installing themes in xUbuntu

Tags: xubuntu, themes

I am currently using XUbuntu 20.04, and I extracted my themes using

> tar -xvf filename.tar.xz

my themes are now in the downloads folder but won't popup in my apperances..
I would like to add that I am a newbie to Linux.
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: These need to be placed in one of two places, global themes directory [/usr/share/themes] to make them available to all users, or the user's theme directory [~/.local/share/themes/]  https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes  ps:  rather than mentioning the LATEST release, it's best if we're told as many users only count LTS releases [20.04], others count all releases [20.10] etc.. thus *latest* doesn't tell us which you mean

Comment: To clarify  20.04  XUbuntu

Comment: :)  The Latest is actually Xubuntu 20.10 or the 2020-October release, which is six months newer than the 2020-April (20.04) release, ie. please be specific as your *latest* release was 2 releases ago.

Answer (score 0):

These need to be placed in one of two places

- global themes directory [`/usr/share/themes`] to make them available to all users, or
- the user's theme directory [`~/.local/share/themes/`]

Refer https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/install_new_themes

Comment: I keep trying to place them but it wont let me, for example, I dragged my themes to my desktop tried dragging them into the themes folder but it does not let me I also tried to change the permissions of the themes folder and it wouldnt let me

Comment: /usr/share/ is outside of area where users have permissions to write, so you need to elevate your privileges (eg. `sudo cp` or `sudo mv`). Any files or directories starting with a "." character won't appear in listings unless *show hidden* is enabled, so whilst `~/.local` is in the user directory, it may not appear by default in `thunar` unless you've told it to display.  If you don't like this answer, try the one I close-voted to (`gksudo` is depreciated so won't exist in recent releases, but `sudo` still works)

Comment: If you don't understand permissions, it maybe safer to use the local `~/.local/share/themes/` directory (ie. have it only available to the current user); it's safer and also can survive a re-install (if no-format is used)

Comment: Could you write me a code of how that would look?

Comment: I created a folder in ~/.local/share/themes/ and then my file manager crashed and got a message saying there was an internal error and I am retrying to access the directory again and it is not showing anything.

Comment: ~ is shorthand for $HOME, or /home/$USER (ie. /home/guiverc/ for me).  On my own box I don't have the directory `/home/guiverc/.local/share/themes` (all my added themes are in /usr/share/themes) so I would `mkdir ~/.local/share/themes` then `cp -prnv [/path/directory] ~/.local/share/themes/`  where [/path/directory] would be replaced by the directory of theme(s) you want to add; -p preserves date, -n so new only (won't add if already there) & -v to be verbose as I prefer to see what occurs to verify it was as expected..  adjust for your needs

Comment: so for example in [/path/directory]  would I put the name of the location of the theme folder or the name of the theme itself?

Comment: Yes.   I might use `cp -prnv ~/Downloads/expanded_the* ~/.local/share/themes` would copy from your $USER directory 'expanded_theme1' 'expanded_theme2' etc into `/home/guiverc/.local/share/themes/` for me (~ gets expanded to /home/guiverc for me)  The "*" will catch any directories that start with "expanded_the" and I've added a "-r" so it will recursively do directories...

Comment: Got this error for another theme im tryna install, [ cp: cannot access '/home/justin/Download/BeautyLine' : Permission denied ]